# Opening hot key application results in error message [LXDE on 19.10]

Tags: shortcut-keys, 19.10, lxde

When trying to set hot keys, I get `Error: Sorry, cannot configure keys remotely`.

This is a pretty fresh install so I can't imagine any of the modifications I've made would cause this behaviour, so maybe something default is not working properly?

[image: Hot key application in menu]

[image: Error message window]

Answer (score 1):

Try Using LXDM. That Fixed it for me. `sudo apt install lxdm`